# Helper for rethrowing exceptions

Tags: java, exception, helper

I often have a situation when a method throws a checked exception so I have to write a wrapper for that method which catches the expetion and rethrow it as uncheched one. I wonder is there any helper-class in Java or in Apache libs for do the same? I'm gonna write my own implementation for that but maybe it exists already.

Comment: Have u visited : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484794/wrapping-a-checked-exception-into-an-unchecked-exception-in-java ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33937382/829571

Comment: guys, have you read the question? It says: is there an _existing_ wrapper because I have to write my own wrapper everytime similar to those from the links you mentioned